# Table just for grouping

Tags: sql

Is it a common case to have a table with a single column for the purpose of grouping rows in another table?

I'm inserting data in batches and I want to have an autoincrement key for each batch to be able to group data based on generated id.

Concretely I want to get from this

```
A
id, x, y, b_id
id PRIMARY KEY
b_id FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES B.id

B
id, timestamp
id PRIMARY KEY

SELECT count(*) as number, B.timestamp FROM A inner join B on A.b_id=B.id
                     where A.x='value' and A.y='value'
                     group by B.id;
```

to

```
A
id, x, y, timestamp, b_id
id PRIMARY KEY
b_id FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES B.id

B
id
id PRIMARY KEY

SELECT count(*) as number, A.timestamp FROM A
                         where A.x='value' and A.y='value'
                         group by A.b_id, A.timestamp;
```

So basically move timestamp to B (denormalize) and use foreign key only for grouping. I want to avoid having join only for the timestamp placed in B. Tables are quite big (60M of rows) and join is very slow. If I still filter on A and have foreign key only for grouping then that would speed up things a lot.

Concretely, I'm using MySQL.

Comment: Table structures and some sample data might make your question a bit clearer. Also, what flavor of SQL are you using. Including columns in your select that aren't in the group by like this isn't usually allowed.

Comment: @TomH I have edited my answer, can you please check it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denormalization can be acceptable for performance reasons. Just make sure that the performance improvement outweighs the cost of that denormalization. There will be costs not only in additional space requirements (which can cause their own performance issues), but also the cost of potential data errors. For example, when two rows end up in table "A" that have the same `b_id`, but different timestamp values.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. "two rows end up in table "A" that have the same b_id, but different timestamp values" can't happen, because b_id and timestamp is always the same for all elements in a batch. What could happen is to have multiple batches with same timestamp, but this is exactly the reason why I'm introducing table B and b_id, so that I don't get wrong count per time instant/batch. Makes sense, yes?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, but I'll just clarify that the same b_id with different timestamp values isn't *supposed* to happen. In a world where everyone writes bug-free code you're all set. ;)

Comment: Yes I agree, because in my case b_id is autoincrement, generated for a batch. But without it, having only timestamps and multiple producers writing to database in parallel it could happen to have multiple rows with same timestamp, making a problem when doing count. Do you agree? :)

Comment: Yes, I agree that you need to account for identical timestamps. What I was saying was that when you denormalize you pay a price. In this case you risk two rows with the same b_id but different timestamps. Even though it should never happen in your application it's still *possible* in the DB and a bug in the software could cause that to happen even if it's not supposed to happen. You just need to be extra careful when dealing with the table. One thing that you can do if MySQL supports it is to create a materialized view on your table (or add a trigger on the table to prevent that to be safe.